# What is The Difference SELECT COUNT(x) on MySQL vs COUNT(x) on PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I read so many articles said MySQL `SELECT COUNT(x)` is faster than `mysql_num_rows($result)` and I never use `mysql_num_rows()`, now I'm using `COUNT($userSuspended)` on my controller. (my web app running on CodeIgniter Framework).

I'm looking for the difference of `SELECT COUNT(x)` on **MySQL** and `COUNT()` on **PHP** performance and I'm always found `SELECT COUNT(x) on MySQL vs mysql_num_rows()`.

Maybe it's not important for you guys. But, I really want to make sure because I want to increase my customer web app performance, so they will not be dissapointed by me. All developers will feel the same.

For example, I have a user table on MySQL contains 7 user. (actually more than 500 users and still counting)

```
| id_user |    user_name   |  status  |  // Table name = users
|    1    | david1234      |     1    |  // 1 is active
|    2    | angel456       |     1    |
|    3    | demian         |     1    |
|    4    | james          |     0    |  // 0 is suspended
|    5    | danny          |     0    |
|    6    | catty          |     1    |
|    7    | zinc           |     0    |
```

I'm usually use this code to get the data of suspended and active users. (in here I will type only suspended code because it's same like active code).

```
// Model
public function getSuspendedUsers() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 0";
    return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
}

// Controller User Function
$userSuspended= $this->usermodel->getSuspendedUsers();
$countSuspended = count($userSuspended);
```

And the result will print like this after passing the data from `controller` to `view`

> Total User Suspended : 3 Users ($countSuspended)

```
| # | id_user |    user_name   |  status  | // Actually the id_user & status are 
| 1 |    4    | james          |     0    | // not shown & not selected in my model
| 2 |    5    | danny          |     0    |
| 3 |    7    | zinc           |     0    |
```

So, the `count` still working on `PHP` not on `MySQL` is there any solution ?

While I'm trying to use `SELECT COUNT(x)` on MySQL, I got some trouble when trying to get the `user_name`

```
// Model
public function getSuspendedUsers() {
    $sql = "SELECT user_name, COUNT(user_name) as count_user FROM users WHERE status = 0";
    return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
}

|    user_name   |  count_user | // It's only show like this
| james          |      3      | // then I can't get all user_name counted
```

**EDIT 1**

Stackoverflow experts answers `query` results :

> Add the result from @Taha Paksu answers

```
// Model
public function getSuspendedUsers() {
    $sql = "SELECT user_name, 
    (SELECT COUNT(user_name) FROM users WHERE status = 0) as count_user
    FROM users WHERE status = 0";
    return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
}

result :
|    user_name   |  count_user | // I think count_user is a redundant data
| james          |      3      | // It's need extra memory cache if more than 100 rows ?
| danny          |      3      | // Because count_user will printed 100 rows 
| zinc           |      3      | // So, it's printed more redundant data. CMIIW
```

Comment: Only use PHP's count, if you want to show the individual entries anyway. If you just want to show the count, use MySQL's version.

Comment: Thank you @Sirko , I'm using count on PHP because I dont want to create 1 more queries only for counting that id_user.

Comment: The main reason is as follows: If you want to use PHP's count, you first have to transfer all (relevant) rows from MySQL to PHP. This is a huge overhead, if you just want to show the number of entries. If, however, you also want to show those very entries you are counting, you have to fetch them anyways, so there is no overhead in counting them in PHP.

Comment: The difference is one counts the number of rows in the MySQL database, and other counts the number of “things” in a PHP script. If you’re counting rows in PHP, that’s _terribly_ inefficient as it means you have to fetch _all_ those rows from the database. So if you need a count of something, do it in an SQL query.

Comment: Hello @MartinBean and @Sirko, so If i'm counting only 20 or 30 rows data suspended may I use `count` rows in PHP ? It's look like I dont need to create extra query only for `count` but I dont know the effect for the performance. Which is better ?

Comment: @Zinc No. Do your counts in MySQL. _That’s_ best for performance.

Comment: So, i will have 2 query for getting the data ? One query for `SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 0` and One more query for `SELECT COUNT(id_user) as countSuspended FROM users WHERE status = 0`. **or** I'm better use Taha Paksu answers on `workaround` for `SELECT user_name, (SELECT COUNT(user_name) FROM users WHERE status = 0) as countSuspended FROM users WHERE status = 0` ? I saw a redundant data on `countSuspended` because `3` as count result is printed 3 times besides the `user_name`. So, which is better ? I'm really appreciate for your help @MartinBean

Comment: Hi @MartinBean, I was add Taha Paksu Result on my question, so you can see the result there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`count`](http://php.net/count) on an array in PHP requires these steps:

1. Execute an SQL query
2. Have the database filter the correct data
3. Send all the data from the database over the wire to PHP
4. Have PHP process the data from the database into an array
5. Have PHP count the array

Whereas a [`COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) in an SQL query merely does this:

1. Execute an SQL query
2. Have the database count the desired entries using whatever optimisation it can apply (e.g. in-memory indices or previously cached results)
3. Send a single integer from the database over the wire to PHP

The latter is obviously fewer steps, requires wrangling of less data and allows the database to apply more possible optimisations to speed up the answer.

If you only need the count, it's insane not to `COUNT` in SQL. If you need the count *and* all the data anyway, then get the data from the database and count it in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already have the answer. First, you have to make a query to MySQL. If you only need the count of the active users, and not the data itself, using

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE WHERE ...
```

is the fastest way to get the count from the database. But, if you are doing a second query to get the suspended users to display their data, then using PHP's count would give you the chance to eliminate one query from the process. It's not about MySQL or PHP, it's about the way you design your code.

**Note**: You can always get the users and count like this:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(1) as suspended_count FROM TABLE WHERE ..
```

To get both user_id's and the count. I don't think it'll slow down your query, but you'll get the chance to eliminate the PHP's count too. But if the server's sql_mode is not set to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` (set as default since mySQL version 5.7.5)

https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-how-to-permanently-change-sql-mode-in-mysql/

Or a workaround:

```
SELECT user_id, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE WHERE ...) as suspended_count 
FROM TABLE WHERE ...
```

Comment: There really is no difference between `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)`. The former is more idiomatic. `SELECT user_id, COUNT(1)` <- this query makes no sense.

Comment: Right, for some reason I though you're emphasizing on `COUNT(1)` since you've used the "fastest" (that's what people usually say) :-)

Comment: Yep, I added * to my last example for you :)

Comment: It's works with workaround, and I got all names with duplicate `suspended_count`, are you sure it's not make the memory cache working harder and the performance is better than `count($userSuspended)` ?

Comment: so `suspended_count` are redundant data, cause only displaying `3` for 3 rows on `user_name` = `james, danny, zinc`

Comment: @Zinc yes, two queries combined as one. The count subquery will be cached (I guess) and it won't be run for each row.

Comment: @TahaPaksu, for example 100 rows printed and `suspended_count` will printed 100 times. How about that Taha ? It will gain more memory cache if i'm not wrong.. CMIIW. Sorry if I'm asking too much..

Comment: I don't know about the details too much, but you won't be needing each suspended_count to a variable. You'll take one of them when needed on PHP side.